# Minecraft 1.9 Data Tags changed?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Ok so I have this command here:

```
/summon Item ~ ~1 ~ {Item:{id:spawn_egg,Damage:65,Count:32,tag:{display:{Name:"Destruction Pellet",Lore:["Place this item in a dispenser and power","to destroy the block infront"]}}}}
```

What it does is summon 32 bat Spawneggs with the name Destruction Pellet. This command works a treat in any 1.8 version (specifically 1.8.0, since that what I use), but when I upgrade to a Minecraft 1.9 snapshot (15w51b) this command now only summons empty spawneggs, as if the **Damage** isn't even there.

So I was wondering if the format/order of Data Tags has changed in the most recent snapshot, or weather this is a bug and it needs to be sumbitted to the Minecraft Bug Tracker.

Comment: Yes, the NBT tag format has changed.  Spawn eggs now take an entire entity NBT tree in the `tag` tag.

Comment: Also, the snapshot may be buggy. But it shouldnt be a problem now. Happy 1.11!

Answer (score 4):

First minor issue is that you have unbalanced quotation marks:

```
["Place this item in a dispenser and power","to destroy the block infront ]
                                             Need to end the string here ^
```

---

As of 1.9, you need to specify data about the entity, including its type, inside of an `EntityTag` compound tag, like this:

```
/summon Item ~ ~1 ~ {Item:{id:spawn_egg,Count:32,tag:{EntityTag:{id:"Bat"},display:{Name:"Destruction Pellet",Lore:["Place this item in a dispenser and power","to destroy the block infront"]}}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the {EntityTag:{id:"Bat"}} they indeed changed that. And btw the damagevalue needs to be 0 for this to work so the command will be /summon Item ~ ~ ~ {Item:{id:"minecraft:spawn_egg",Count:32b,tag:{display:{Name:"Destuction Pellet"},EntityTag:{id:"Bat"}}}c